# Accessing another array by index

Tags: javascript, jsrender

My data are in the form:

```
data = { arr_id:[0,2,5], arr_description:["description 0","description 2","description 5"]}
```

My template

```
<script id="tmp" type="text/x-jsrender">
<ul>
        {{for arr_id}}
            <li>id: {{>}} **I NEED THIS->** {{:agg_desc[#Index]}} </li>
        {{/for}}
</ul>
</script>
```

The arrays `arr_id` `arr_description` maps same data (the one with an ID the latter with a description) I want to iterate over the first one and use the `#index` to access the second one.

Comment: You could reduce the object first, and combine `arr_id` with `arr_description`.

Comment: Your indexes are still `0`, `1`, and `2`... `arr_description[5]` would be `undefined`. Just iterate `arr_description` as you would any other array.

Comment: I edited the code, maybe I was not clear, I need to access arr_description with the same index of arr_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in the arr_description array to the inner context.

Here are some relevant links:

- [Accessing parent data](http://www.jsviews.com/#parentdata)
- [Contextual parameters](http://www.jsviews.com/#contextualparams)

For example, you can do this:

```
{{for arr_id ~arr_desc=arr_description}}
  <li>id: {{>}}  {{:~arr_desc[#index]}} </li>
{{/for}}
```

or this:

```
{{for arr_id}}
  <li>id: {{>}}  {{:~root.arr_description[#index]}} </li>
{{/for}}
```

Comment: Basically you can even inject data in the inner context! I really like jsrender :)